# copy frames from video file recording

Tags: c++, opencv

I start a recording session from webcam and then I want to make another file with 200 frames already recorded and then the other realtime frames from the webcam.

I made this to get frames from the "Blob.avi" file that is recording:

```
        VideoWriter writeVideo;

        VideoCapture savedVideo;
        savedVideo.open("E:\\Blob.avi");

        int startFrame = savedVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
        cout << " startFrame:"<< startFrame;
        startFrame -= 200; 
        savedVideo.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,startFrame);
        cout <<"-"<< startFrame << " ms: " << savedVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) << endl;

        sprintf_s(filename,150, "E:\\FramesTest.avi");
        writeVideo.open(filename,xvid, 10, Size(640,480));
        Mat tempPic;
        for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ){
            savedVideo >> tempPic;
            writeVideo.write(tempPic);
        }
       //then add realtime frames.
```

The problem is that it can't read total frames in the file that is recording: it gives me 0 and also the ms. This way it starts the new file recording realtime without copying first the 200 frames of the other file.

I think the problem is that the file video is in use.
So how can I copy some frames from a not released file video?

EDIT:
I must add at least 30ms of delay:

```
        for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ){
            savedVideo >> tempPic;
            writeVideo.write(tempPic);
            Sleep(30)
        }
```

This way it works, also if it starts from frame 0 minus 200 instead of subtracting 200 from the last frame.
But it's a lot slow: I loose about 10 seconds of realtime capture.
Also because there is a re-encoding of each frame.
So I think it should be better recording first the realtime capture and then add the 200 frames at the beginning of the newly created file.
How can I achieve this? possibly witout re-encoding, better at file-level.

The purpose of this is to make a video when there is some blob detection, including some seconds of video before the blob triggered.

Comment: What OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: Bottom line, you are trying to append frames to an existing file, right?

Comment: I use 2.4.3 and yes, I'm reading frames from the file being recording and then append them at a newly created file.